# django installation not working in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, installation

I created a virtual environment and installed django in it using pip. In a python shell in the v.e. I can `import django` and print its version, but when trying to start a project or do a `django-admin --version` I get the following error:
**bash: /usr/bin/django-admin: No such file or directory**

Here are the steps I took before:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv my_env
source my_env/bin/activate
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
pip --version
sudo apt install python3-django
django-admin --version --> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
sudo apt remove python3-django
pip install django  --> Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 django-3.1.7 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
django-admin --version  --> bash: /usr/bin/django-admin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# to check version
>>> django-admin.py version

# to create a project
>>> django-admin startproject myproject

# useful
>>> django-admin help
```

More about django admin commands https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/